# timestamp case sensitive

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-9

Is the function `Now()` in ColdFusion case sensitive?  Can I use `now()` instead of `Now()`?

Comment: No and Yes. But the best way to answer this type of question is to experiment. Try it and see what happens :)

Comment: lol... you should have just tried it yourself, takes you a second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, not case sensitive. No ColdFusion functions are case sensitive.